# `Rcpp::wrap` and `Rcpp::as` for external classes that use Rcpp namespace classes

Tags: r, rcpp, s-expression

How can `Rcpp::wrap` and `Rcpp::as` methods be written for classes that contain an `Rcpp` class?

For example, the following `.cpp` file compiles using `sourceCpp()`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace Rcpp {
  class myVector {
  public:
    NumericVector data;
    myVector(NumericVector v) : data(v) {};
  };

  template <> myVector as(SEXP v) { 
    return myVector(v);
  }

  template <> SEXP wrap(const myVector& v) { 
    return v.data;
  }
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::myVector test(Rcpp::myVector& x){
  return x;
}
```

In this example, we create a vector that is comprised simply of a single Rcpp class (`NumericVector`) and an `Rcpp::as` and `Rcpp::wrap` method so that it can be used as an argument in any exported function.

However, the code does not pass when creating an Rcpp package as follows:

1. Rstudio -> New Project -> New Directory -> R package using Rcpp
2. Copy above script into new file, `test.cpp`
3. Build -> Install and Restart

There are no complaints about the `test.cpp` but there are complaints in `src/RcppExports.cpp`. Here's the relevant function:

```
// test
Rcpp::myVector test(Rcpp::myVector& x);
RcppExport SEXP _test_test(SEXP xSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::myVector& >::type x(xSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(test(x));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
```

The errors are:

```
Line 19: `myVector` does not name a type;
Line 24: `myVector` was not declared in this scope
... template argument 1 invalid, qualified-id in declaration, 'x' not declared, 'test' not declared... side-effects of above two errors.
```

I do know how to write `Rcpp::as` and `Rcpp::wrap` for classes that do NOT contain Rcpp classes ([templated case](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/), [general case](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf)):

1. `#include <RcppCommon.h>`
2. Forward-declaration of class, may depend on C++ libraries (not `Rcpp.h`)
3. `#include <Rcpp.h>`

Unfortunately, `Rcpp::myVec` requires `Rcpp.h` and thus cannot be declared prior to including `Rcpp.h`.

Can external classes containing Rcpp classes make use of `Rcpp::wrap` and `Rcpp::as`? If so, is there any precedent I can view for details? I haven't found any despite quite a bit of searching, or maybe I'm overlooking something very simple.

Comment: I think your best bet way be a simplification where you only have Rcpp classes at the interface to R, and standard C++ (possibly using Armadillo or Eigen or ... ) on the inside.  The glue code is powerful, but it cannot read your mind about interfaces you want translated and others you don't.  (Though we do have 'register' to declare what you want to access from R and what from C++, but isn't all that easy to use or well-documented.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel All true, but it's "less convenient" (third-world problem) to not wrap in an Rcpp-derived class directly at the interface to R. This means that the end-user needs to manually construct myClass from the underlying Rcpp structures (i.e. S4).  For instance, I was thinking a macro in the Rcpp library code could enable extending Rcpp::wrap for S4 classes. I guess I have no option but to let folks do it directly.

Comment: Your approach still makes no sense to me (likely because there is no [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). _If_ the underlying classes are R-exportable, maybe just export them and don't insist on a 'hiding layer'?  Anyway, I am sure you will figure it out.  When you have a more concrete and tangible question, by all means bring it here.

Comment: Well, as an example consider the dgCMatrix class. It contains "i", "p", and "x" slots of IntegerVector, IntegerVector, NumericVector. My only option in a package is to have users write R interface functions using S4 (which could refer to _absolutely any_ S4 object) and then construct the Rcpp::dgcMatrix class from that S4 object. If would be nice to pass in a "dgCMatrix" S4 class (specifically) as an Rcpp::dgCMatrix, and behind the scenes Rcpp will call the relevant method for wrapping that S4 class to said C++ class.

Comment: You cannot have a compile-time guarantee for an S4 that is a `dgCMatrix`. You can only have a `Rcpp::S4` and then check-and-dispatch at run-time which S4 class it is.